# Fantasy anime series with people from another world doing quests

Tags: story-identification, anime

I'm trying to find out how an anime is called where I once saw a youtube clip.

The protagonist and others are appearing in a fantasy world and they themselves hail from our world but have no memory of their past...but still all of their old skills.

Upon arrival they are grouped together and learn a "class" at an instructor. The MC is a thief whilt the party also has a mage, a ranger, a "tank" (no clue what class) and a cleric. I think there was one or more others too but don't remember it exactly.

The party then set out to fullfill quests. Here it is quite realistically as they at first can't bring themselves to kill the monsters and have troubles with that (although the monsters have no troubles killing them). Then later on they get into an ambush and the cleric (the leader) is killed and the thief becomes the new leader.

That is about all I remember.

Edit: One thing I just remembered from the animation style it seems its a relatively new anime...mabe 5 years or younger.

Comment: Do you still have a link to the youtube clip?

Comment: @SpacePhoenix sadly nope else it would have been quite easy to find it

Comment: Ok,  give description of the characters. How many, clothes, hair color,  style, males,  females.  How long ago was this YouTube clip?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Grimgar of Fantasy and Ash 2016
[Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grimgar_of_Fantasy_and_Ash)

The story begins by showing a group of novice adventurers battling goblins in a forest. The party seems utterly out of their element and is forced to flee. From there we discover through flash back and dialog that the party, who likely originate from modern earth, woke with a large group of people on this world just a few weeks ago.

With no memory of how they arrived and no other options they are quickly pressed into service as Trainee Volunteer Soldiers by a mysterious individual named Chief Britney. Some take to this better than others. The party we have been following is composed of the left over individuals who didn’t.

Led by a man named Manato they have banded together, joined class guilds, and begun hunting weak monsters as a way to grow stronger and earn the money they need to survive. Initially things do not go well. Eventually however, the party learns to work as a unit and experiences enough success hunting goblins to move from the forest to a ruined city. There Manato dies saving them from ambush and leaves the responsibility for the group to the thief Haruhiro.

Thrown into despair, the party is fractured and grieves for their lost friend never having realized just how much Manato did to hold them all together. Once the party comes to terms with their loss, they take on a new Priest named Merry.

Merry is initially distant and broken from the loss of her own party, for which she blames herself, but gradually comes to regard Haruhiro and the party as friends though she remains distant. Back to full strength the party seeks to avenge Manato by striking at the heart of the goblin encampment in the ruins. After slaying the goblin king the party finds closure and decides to help Merry do the same by moving their monster hunting to the kobold infested mines where her old party fell.

The season ends with Merry's past behind her and the surviving heroes coming to terms with the life and death nature of their time on the world of Grimgar.